# add suffix h in between hours and minutes in the_modified_time function in php

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

I am working on a code as shown below. It gives the following o/p:  16 07

```
 <?php the_modified_time('G i') ?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that it displays:

**16 h 07**

I tried adding h in **between G and i** but its predefined in php.

Comment: Try escaping `G \h i`

Comment: like this ?   `<?php the_modified_time('G \h i') ?>`

Comment: @flash See Example #2 in [the documentation of date/time formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Yes, if `the_modified_time` is using the `date` format.

Comment: how can we know `the_modified_time` is using the `date` format ?

Comment: @flash You seem to be using Wordpress.  [See Here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2512).  The comment on that line says "The time format. Accepts 'G', 'U', or php date format."

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes, I am using wordpress.